# How does one stay informed about changes to Apple's frameworks?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, upgrade, changelog

After several hours of digging, I found out that apparently the behaviour of Security Framework changed from XCode 8.3 to 9.0: when creating instances of `SecKey` (RSA private keys in my case) from `Data`, leading zeroes were suddenly a concern. On iOS only, not on macOS. Maybe it was the jump from iOS 10 to 11?

I checked the release notes for Swift 4.0, XCode 9.0, and iOS 11.0 -- no mention of Security Framework at all.

What are ways to stay informed about such changes? Does Apple publish comprehensive changelogs anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the changes here
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

I have found that changes to Security Framework was made in 10.0 version.

Comment: That's the list I checked. All was good with XCode 8.3 and iOS 10.3, so the change needs to be more recent.